# How to convert a 3D equation into 1D equation

Tags: discrete-mathematics, optimization, linear-programming

I want to  convert the following 3D equation  into a 1D equation:

(note: x = y)

P = x + y + z = 100

A = A(x,y,z)=√((50(50-x)(50-y)(50-z) )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since $x=y$,

$$z=100-2x$$

$$A=\sqrt{50(2x-50)(50-x)^2}=(500-10x)\sqrt{x-25}$$